# Internal and external channels of ADC in a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, adc

I am trying to select a microcontroller for my project. I need four ADC channels to sense various voltages and currents. In the datasheets of μC devices, internal ADC channels and external ADC channels are mentioned.

Can someone explain what is the meaning of this and also what is the difference between internal and external ADC channels.

for example:

- MSP430 has 8 external and 2 internal channels.
- STM8S105 writes 8 internal channels.

Comment: You should really copy and paste the verbatim text from the datasheets.

Comment: Yes, as per the above comment, please clarify by pasting text verbatim.

Comment: Hi Marcus, Here is the link to the datasheet from cyprus. Page No 6 shows the ADC block. :-   http://www.cypress.com/file/139841/download

Comment: Page 6 doesn't mention anything about external ADC channels. Can you clarify? Do you mean internal versus external voltage references?

Comment: @Rishi: Posting the link means that you intend that we all download the datasheet, find the page and find the text on the page. It's your question so you need to do that work and post the information as requested.

Comment: @transistor - Sorry to offend but I would not mind making a few more clicks from my mouse if that really helps someone.

Comment: @Andy - Yes, It doesnt say external. It says "8 internal channels" . That is my doubt. Why it says internal when I can connect to the external pins P3.0 to P3.7

Answer (score 4):

External channels are linked to pins so you can connect any analog signal to them.

Internal channels are connected to specific signals inside the microcontroller, typically a voltage reference or a temperature sensor. These channels can only be used to read these signals.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of guessing, since you're not referring to any verbatim text, but:

With "internal channels", the manufacturer probably refers to the number of actual ADC devices inside the microcontroller.

Now, ADCs are pretty fast, so most microcontrollers can be programmed to first measure the voltage on input pin X, store it in memory, then measure the voltage on input pin Y, store it in memory, and repeat, for example.

Using this ADC plexing, you can sample a lot more different inputs than you have "real" ADCs without any disadvantage. Those might be your "external channels".